# Way to limit number of columns in CSV logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

So, I have lots of logs that are tab delimited. They should each have seven columns each. Like this:

> "Time", "Time2", "NUM", "Other_NUM", "PROG", "PID", "MESSAGE"

The problem I have here is the MESSAGE could have tabs in it, which makes logstash store it in column8 and column9. I was wondering if there is a way to make logstash not add columns and just merge all of the extra columns on the end of MESSAGE?

Right now I've got a mutate like this:

```
        mutate 
    {
        add_field => { "MSG" => "%{MSG} %{column8} %{column9}" }
        remove_field => [ "column8", "column9" ]
    }
```

But for most of the logs there isn't going to be a column 8, and even less logs will have a column 9. They could also have 50 columns for all I know. So I was wondering if there was a method to limit the number of columns.

Comment: Is each of your column tab-delimited or comma-delimited. Also what is the delimiter for each row

Comment: Tab-delimited, and each row is one a new line.